# What does "Energize" do?

Tags: card-hunter

During campaign play, I had an enemy use a card called "Energize" on me. All the card says is "restores target's action point".

What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll notice that once an enemy unit attacks you, it becomes gray and you are assured that that specific unit will not attack you again on the current turn. When a different enemy unit "Energize"s a grayed out unit, it becomes colorful again and may attack you yet again on the same turn.